# Restoring content database on SQL Server throws error database size limit

Tags: 2013, sql-server, backup, content-database, restore

We a standalone SharePoint 2013 server with SQL Server Express. I have received a content database backup file of ~50MB. When I try to restore this content database backup file in our SQL Server Express I get error as

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: CREATE DATABASE or ALTER DATABASE failed because the resulting cumulative database size would exceed your licensed limit of 10240 MB per database. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

I checked and found that the cumulative size of all DB files on SQL Server Express is ~3.5GB.

I am not sure what exactly is the problem here as the backup expands to size of ~200MB only, and there's ample space in SQL for that. Any pointers would be helpful as to where we need to look so that we can resolve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the content database has unnecessary allocated space (most probably transaction log file)

you can try setting database recovery model to simple and shrinking the database before taking the backup.